# Hooking up a NEMA 6-30p heater to a 6-50r socket

Tags: electrical, adapter

I'm renting a garage, and it gets too cold in the winter to work comfortably. I ordered an electric 30 Amp rated space heater but realized that I have a 50 Amp, NEMA 6-50r receptacle. Obviously I cannot just use a straight-through adapter or different plug because that would defeat the safety of the expected 30 Amp breaker circuit. However, would it be safe to create an adapter where it goes from a 6-50p pigtail, into a circuit breaker box with a 30 Amp breaker, which is wired to a NEMA 6-30r receptacle? All this would be using properly sized wire and grounding of course. Being a rented space, I don't want to be installing any permanent fixtures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Your plan will absolutely work, and be safe.  Make sure you properly use flexible cable (likely SOOW) with the breaker box you put together, and consider strain relief where the cable exits the box.

However, the cheaper route you mentioned, isn't as dangerous as you think.....

Consider any device you plug into a normal 15amp outlet.  Very often, the circuit, and breaker are 20amp, even when the outlet has a  15 amp style receptacle.  Say you're plugging in a cellphone charger.  It needs 0.1 amp.  Yet your circuit breaker exposes it to 200 times that!  Omg let's freak out and build a special subpanel at the outlet to provide a breaker appropriate for the cell phone charger.  Wait.  Nobody does that.

Plugging a 30 amp device into a 50 amp outlet is no worse than plugging a 0.1 amp device into a 15 amp outlet.  Just change the plug and be done with it.

But if you enjoy building sub panels, enjoy this project!  If you build a special sub panel just for this, you should consider adding 20 amp breakers and outlets to it also.  Could end up being super convenient to have.

Comment: If the heater would short out internally, isn't it the case that the 50-A breaker would trip before any significant heating of the (30-A rated) power cord or internal conductors would occur? So the only condition which would cause damage and be a risk of fire would be if the heater or its cord would fail and start passing say 48 A.  Of course, if there was somehow a fire and the instructions for the heater in fact say to use a max 30 A breaker, then there could be some legal consequences.

Comment: Breakers in your breaker panel AREN'T FOR protecting things plugged in to the outlet from going over current.  Breakers are for protecting the fixed writing and receptacles permanently installed in the structure.  That said, a dead short inside the appliance means thousands of amps, and would likely trip the breaker.  If the heater instructions say anything if the sort, it would likely be 'do not modify'. In which case of you really care, buy or make an adapter cord with a male 50a and female 30a.  Make sure both of their screw terminals are rated to accept the gauge wire you're using.

Comment: So I decided to go ahead and build a box with a breaker. Even if it doesn't really add much safety it's a good project for me to get familiar with home wiring. I ended up only finding 10-3 SOOW cable, which should be fine since I have a 30 Amp breaker. The breaker is a double slot two circuit model rated for 30 Amps. I assume then that I put the black("hot") and white("neutral") through each side of the breaker and hook the ground up to the ground bar, and ground the metal boxes. Does it matter which side of the 6-30 I hook the black up to?

Comment: You need two breakers because you're using an underrated infeed cable.  And could add more loads too the panel in the future.  Both breakers should be double pole.  Never connect a neutral to a breaker.  The 10-3 should have a red and a black hot.  Those go to the terminals on one breaker.  The 6-30's two hots go to the two terminals in the other breaker.  Grounds so go to the ground bar.  Neutral to a separate, insulated neutral bar.

Comment: I misspoke when I said neutral, was using the terminology used with the plug instructions but it's actually two hot wires and one ground wire. Isn't a single double pole circuit breaker (the style rated for 240v that occupies two breaker slots) what is needed? One hot going through one pole, the other hot going through the other? There will not be any other circuits added to this box in the future, it is using a breaker box with only room for the one breaker.

Comment: It's a tough call.  If this is not permanently installed equipment, code becomes irrelevant.  If you're certain no other breakers will be added then it's not necessary to use the second breaker.  I really would have fought hard to find a 50 amp rated cable though.  Camco i think, makes basically oven extension cords, for use on RVs with a 50 amp service.  Cut the female of that and use in your panel.

Comment: There was some 6-3 that was absolutely massive. It is not permanently installed like you say. Copper 10-3 is rated to 30 amps, although I would have liked if they had 8-3 available. Wouldn't 50-amp rated cable be overkill for a breaker box with a 30 amp breaker connected to a single 30 amp receptacle? I can always special order the 8-3 if that would be the better choice.

Comment: Here's the thing.  Your in feed isn't connected to a breaker, is it?  It's connected to the bus bars. Or to a main breaker in that sub panel.  The bus bars are probably rated for 125 amps.  The 'panel' is probably rated for 125.  So anything upstream should handle 125, or have a breaker upstream of the bus bars that can limit to the maximum safe capacity of the in feed cable.  "I'm not going to add circuits to the subpanel" isn't really something you can say.  The whole point of a panel is to be able to add circuits.

Comment: If you really had no intention of adding circuits, they sell service disconnects with breakers in them.  Those don't have bus bars, and by design can not at circuits.

Comment: The feed is actually coming from a 50-amp breaker already. So from what you're saying the cable between the 6-50r and my 30-amp breaker would ideally be rated 50 amps? For the box I got I really can say I'm not adding more circuits, it's less a subpanel and more a glorified box for a single breaker. I appreciate you sharing your expertise. Btw, stackechange is recommending to move the discussion to chat but I do not have enough reputation, so feel free to do so if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple and inexpensive fix is to down-size the breaker. And then simply replace the receptacle.